# Converting circular structure to JSON in Vue

Tags: json, vue.js, vuejs3, circular-reference

A complete testsuit is failing with the error below.

Test suite failed to run

```
**TypeError:** Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
    --- property '_renderProxy' closes the circle
    at stringify (<anonymous>)

  at messageParent (node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/messageParent.js:34:19)
```

I tried checking all the api call and checked all the async calls.
I tried to use JSONC but that didn't work. Also I have not used JSON.stringify in my testsuit anywhere.

Comment: The question cannot be answered in its current form, please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The error means that some Vue internal object has been stringified in tests, this likely hasn't been done by your code directly. Probably happens when some extra output occurs in tests, e.g. with an error.